# Is There an Easier Way to Load Spring OAuth Client Configuration

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I'm working on a little proof of concept for a set of endpoints that need to be able to call each other passing tokens which are obtained via an OAuth 2 client credentials flow. I'm using Spring Boot and related projects to build these endpoints, and I'm confused as to why the framework appears to be very opinionated about the following code:

```
package com.example.client;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientContext;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestOperations;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.client.ClientCredentialsResourceDetails;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableOAuth2Client;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableOAuth2Client
@RestController
public class StuffClient {

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri}")
    private String tokenUrl;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.id}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.client-secret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.grant-type}")
    private String grantType;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate;

    private String uri = "http://localhost:8082/stuff/";

    @RequestMapping(value = "/client/{stuffName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String client(@PathVariable("stuffName") String stuffName) {
        String request = uri + stuffName;
        return restTemplate.getForObject(request, String.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext clientContext) {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource(), clientContext);
    }

    @Bean
    protected OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource() {
        ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resource = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
        resource.setAccessTokenUri(tokenUrl);
        resource.setClientId(clientId);
        resource.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        resource.setGrantType(grantType);
        return resource;
    }
}
```

And the accompanying configuration file:

```
server:
  port: 8081

security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
  oauth2:
    client:
      id: test-client
      client-secret: test-secret
      access-token-uri: http://localhost:8080/uaa/oauth/token
      grant-type: client_credentials
```

The above works exactly as expected. If I change `security.oauth2.client.id` to `security.oauth2.client.client-id` (in both the Java code and the YAML), I get a 500 error, the first line of which is:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2AccessDeniedException: Unable to obtain a new access token for resource 'null'. The provider manager is not configured to support it.
```

The code also works fine if I hard code values for all of the instance variables. It seems to work fine, in fact, in every permutation of populating those instance variables except the one where I use `@Value` to populate `clientId` with the value of `security.oauth2.client.client-id`

So my main question is: is the framework actually opinionated in this very specific way? And if so, why? And, can I leverage this opinionated-ness to simplify my code?

Comment: I am facing same issue did you resolved it

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which spring-boot version you are using. I am using spring-boot version `1.5.4.RELEASED` and to simplify your codes,

you can inject [OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/resource/OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails.html) like

```
@Autowired
private OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource;
```

and create [OAuth2RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestTemplate.html) as

```
@Bean
@Primary
public OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext clientContext) {
    return new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource, clientContext);
}
```

sample yaml ..

```
### OAuth2 settings ### 
security:
  user:
    password: none
  oauth2:
    client:
      accessTokenUri: ${auth-server}/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: ${auth-server}/oauth/authorize
      clientId: myclient
      clientSecret: secret
    resource:
      user-info-uri: ${auth-server}/sso/user
      jwt:
        keyValue: |
          -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
          your public key
          -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

And then,use `restTemplate` instance in controllers as

```
@Autowired
private OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate;
```

I hope some helps for you.